# Avoiding Validations while Editing in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using below given class model (MVC 3 using C#) to register an employee. Password/Confirm password fields are used at the time of new registration.
When I edit an existing employee, I don't want to update/fill their password/confirm password again, but because of given validations (on password and confirm password) it doesn't let me update rest of the information for employee.

```
 public class EmployeeModel
    {   
    ....
    ....
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is must")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Password can be maximum 20 chars long")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Password can be maximum 20 chars long")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Not a valid password, must be atleast 5 chars long")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password and Confirm password do not match")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
    }
```

My questions are: Should I create another model class for editing an employee (This new model will not have password/confirm password field)? But I find it problematic because this kind of situation can arise with some other modules as well and I don't want to end up having two model classes for each module.

OR Should I load the password/confirm password field while editing but hide them from user ? 
Do above steps make sense? What other ways are possible ?

Comment: create a separate model for editing with no password at all or make it optional if you dont want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is concept of [viewmodal](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx). Create separate modal for every view to avoid such situation

Answer (score 0):

If you editor view requires different field and validation then its better to create a proper view model for editing view. That MVC so enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to Create another model class.

You can work with the existing model class and if you dont want any fields to include in validations you can remove them from your ModelState.

This is how you should do it :

```
public ActionResult Edit(EmployeeModel empmodel)
{

        ModelState.Remove("Password");
        ModelState.Remove("ConfirmPassword");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          //do something
        }

}
```

Hope it helps